# Android Application communication serial data

Tags: java, android, youtube, bluetooth, serial-port

I am making a Bluetooth app which connects to a Bluetooth transmitter/receiver which is transmitting serial data. The Bluetooth device will eventually be connected to sensors and these sensors will provide data which needs to be displayed on my phone. As of now am using the simulation software CoolTerm to send data back and forth between my app and the external Bluetooth device. Currently I have successfully made the app detect and connect to devices. But I am running into some problems:

1. Firstly does any one know how to install CoolTerm( its available on Mac and windows technically speaking), but when I try to install it on Ubuntu it gives no executable file like it did on windows. Anyone who knows how to install this on ubuntu please provide me the steps I have already downloaded the Linux version tar ball from there website and unziped it.
2. Although on successful connection my app sends a string which is received by the Bluetooth device I am not able to receive data back. The way I have things currently set up I expect a toast message to pop-up telling me I have received data when the external Bluetooth device transmits to me. The CoolTerm software allows you to send data but this is for some reason not being displayed on my app. Any ideas?
3. Lastly anyone know a good text box widget or something I can use in my app to send data to the external Bluetooth device. Right now I have the app send a string as soon as it connects.

Here is a YouTube link: I have made some minor changes to this as the code will suggest.

Click [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r55C77_ohi8"youtube video of app")!
Click [here](https://drive.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/0BwRY4KO_k7sUSGpLX0o4TDFCOFk"cleaner code formmatt")!

Here is the code

```
package com.example.intellicyclemobileside;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ToggleButton toggle_discovery;
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevicesList;
    ArrayList<String> unpairedDevicesList;
    ArrayList<String> combinedDevicesList;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    Set<String> unpairedDevices;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    String selectedFromList;
    String selectedFromListName;
    String selectedFromListAddress;
    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice;

/*
    public BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    public BluetoothDevice mmDevice;*/
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;
    final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;


    Handler mHandler = new Handler(){           
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                // Do Something;
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CONNECTED",0).show();
                String s = "This string proves a socket connection has been established!!";
                connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),string,0).show();

        break;
        }       
    }
};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findDevices);
    toggle_discovery =  (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.deviceDiscoverable);
    pairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    unpairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    unpairedDevices = new HashSet<String>();
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); 

    // Sets up Bluetooth
    enableBT();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searching for devices, please wait... ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Checks for known paired devices
            pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();   
            displayCominedDevices();
            //mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
           }
         });

toggle_discovery.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
    makeDicoverable(1);
    } else {
       // The toggle is disabled
       makeDicoverable(0);
      }
    }
});

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    selectedFromList = (String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    /*Debugging
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedFromList,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        String[] parts = selectedFromList.split(" ");
    selectedFromListName = parts[0];
    selectedFromListAddress = parts[1];
    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = selectedDevice(selectedFromListAddress);
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
    ct.start();
    //ConnectThread ConnectThread = new ConnectThread(selectedDevice);
    //connectDevice();
    /* Debug Help
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedFromListName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedFromListAddress,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedDevice.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
         }
  });
}


public void displayCominedDevices(){
    displayPairedDevices();
    displayDetectedDevices();
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,removeDuplicates(unpairedDevicesList,pairedDevicesList));
    listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
}

public BluetoothDevice selectedDevice(String deviceAddress){
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothDevice device;     
    device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
    return device;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public String checkState(BluetoothSocket mmSocket2){
    String state = "NOT_KNOWN";

    if (mmSocket2.isConnected() == true){
        state = "STATE_CONNECTED";
    }
        state = "STATE_DISCONNECTED";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return state;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<String> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> s1, ArrayList<String> s2){
    /*Debugging 
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "unpairedList " + s1.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "pairedList " + s2.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */
    combinedDevicesList =  new ArrayList<String>();
    combinedDevicesList.addAll(s1);
    combinedDevicesList.addAll(s2);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set Unique_set = new HashSet(combinedDevicesList);
    combinedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>(Unique_set);
    /*Debugging 
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Combined List" + combinedDevicesList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); */
    return combinedDevicesList;
}

public void enableBT(){
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is not suppourted on Device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
       int resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK;
        if(resultCode < 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Accept Enabling Bluetooth Request!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabling Bluetooth FAILED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public void displayPairedDevices(){
    // If there are paired devices
    enableBT();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in loop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Loop through paired devices
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            String s = " ";
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
            pairedDevicesList.add(deviceName + s + deviceAddress +" \n");
            //listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


        /*
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pairedDevicesList);
        listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);*/
    }
}

public void displayDetectedDevices(){
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            /* Debugging help
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),action,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            // When discovery finds a device
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                /* Debugging help
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
                String s = " ";
                unpairedDevices.add(deviceName + s + deviceAddress +" \n");
                //unpairedDevicesList.add(deviceName + s + deviceAddress +" (un-paired)\n");
                unpairedDevicesList = new ArrayList<String>(unpairedDevices);
            }
        }
    };
    /*adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,unpairedDevicesList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/
    // Register the BroadcastReceiver      
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), unpairedDevicesList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void makeDicoverable(int option){
    Intent discoverableIntent;
    if (option == 1){
        discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,120);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open discovery for 2mins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 1);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open discovery is OFF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
/*Un-used Method
public void compareAddress(BluetoothDevice checkDevice,String address){
    if((checkDevice.getAddress().equals(address))){

        selectedDevice = checkDevice;
    }   

}*/

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to device failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                return;
        }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
            mHandler.obtainMessage(SUCCESS_CONNECT, mmSocket).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
           } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

}   
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {


    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer; // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);


        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your device is a 'Bluetooth to UART converter' module, then, make a loop-back connection at module (i.e. short TXD with RXD). Send test strings from your app to the module and expect to receive it back as well. Depending on results of such test your app or/and module can be probed further to recover real issue, if any.